# Using chkconfig to implement auto-start on RHEL7?

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd, rhel7, chkconfig

I'm moving an in-house application from RHEL6 to RHEL7 servers.

I read you should still be able to use 
`chkconfig` and `service` commands to install start/stop scripts, even if they have now changed to **systemd** boot-up:

> Although you can still use the service and chkconfig commands to
>   start/stop and enable/disable services, respectively, they are not
>   100% compatible with the RHEL 7 systemctl command ... ( https://access.redhat.com/articles/754933 )

I follow the RHEL6 procedure (`chkconfig --add myscript; chkconfig myscript on`) and get it working, so you can manually do:

```
  sudo service myscript start
  sudo service myscript stop
```

This works fine.

But what is **not** working is that the application should **auto-start** when you reboot the Linux-server. The start-script never gets invoked after `reboot`.

Is this one of the "incompatibilities" under RHEL7?
Or is there a way to fix this, too?

Not able to figure this out....
we still have a mix of RHEL6 and RHEL7 servers, so would prefer if I can continue the `chkconfig` solution, for now.

Comment: You should use the right tools on the right platform. That way you know it will work. Besides, once you get over the initial "what is this" of SystemD, you'll find it to be much better than the sysvinit system.

Comment: OK... it's just this situation as I wrote, as long as we still have a mix of RHEL6 and RHEL7 servers, would prefer if we could use the SAME init-config on both systems --- if that's not possible, I wish Redhat were more explicit in their advices --- in my world, "not 100% compatible" is a bit different from "broken" :)